# Can't Connect to Hostinger oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle

I can't connect to my hostinger oracle database. When I try I get "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'Connection request timed out'"
I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client and I set up a remote connection on hostinger.
This is the code I'm using:

```
OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection();  
OracleConnectionStringBuilder stringBuilder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();  
stringBuilder.Password = "NotFakePassword";  
stringBuilder.UserID="NotFakeUserName";  
stringBuilder.DataSource = "hostname:port/database";  
connection.ConnectionString = stringBuilder.ConnectionString;  
connection.Open();  
connection.Close();
```

Comment: use `ConnectionTimeout` in your stringBulder.

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya I've set the timeout to 70 and I still get the same issue.

Comment: Extending timeout usually accomplishes nothing but delaying the inevitable error.  have you tested basic network connectivity?  Try to ping hostname.  I trust that the values you show for your stringBuilder.DataSource are for posting purposes and not the actual values you use.

Comment: @EdStevens I can ping the hostname. Yup the values I provided were for the sake of posting and not the credentials I use to try to connect.

Comment: Can you please check if you can connect to the service (e.g. using `telnet hostname port`)?

Comment: @Markus I don't have telnet. I can however connect to it via mysql workbench. So I know the credentials are right along with the port number.